# A base generates an unique topology?

Tags: general-topology

I was confused by this.

- Let $X$ be {$a,b,c$},
- Let $\mathcal{B}$ be {{$a$},{$b$},{$c$}}.
- Let $ \mathcal{T}$ be {$X, \emptyset$, {$a$}, {$b$}, {$a,b$}}.
- Let $ \mathcal{T'}$ be {$X, \emptyset$, {$a$}, {$c$}, {$a,c$}}

My textbook states the definition for basis is:

> If $X$ is a set, a *basis* for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that
>
> 1. for each $x \in X$. there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$
> 2. if $x$ belongs to intersection of two basis element $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ such that $B_3$ containing $x$ and is contained in the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$

Hence, $\mathcal{B}$ satisfy basis definitions. So $\mathcal{B}$ is basis for two different topology on $X$.

But this seems wrong, because [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29) states that there is a unique topology on $X$ for which $\mathcal{B}$ is a base.

Comment: @bof I kind of figure it out now. There is additional definition on "topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$"

Comment: The quoted definition puts conditions on the basis $\mathcal B$ but does not mention a topology $\mathcal T.$ It tells you when $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology, but does not tell you what topology it's a basis for. So how did you pick $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal T'$? Do think that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for the topology $\mathcal T''=\{\emptyset,X\}$? If not, why not?

Comment: **First,** there is a definition of what it means for something to be a basis for a **given** topology. The viewpoint is that you have a topology to start with and you find a basis. For example, the Euclidean topology of the plane, the basis could be open discs, or open rectangles, or something else. What you quoted is the answer to the question: if I'm just given a set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal B$ of subsets, is this a basis for some topology? The answer is yes iff the stated conditions hold. The topology is unique; it consists of all unions of subcollections of $\mathcal B.$

Comment: @bof, thanks for the help, have figured it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition (2), it is important to point that we must have $x \in B_3$, such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Let's organize our thoughts.

You have fixed a topological space $(X, {\cal T})$. A collection ${\cal B}\subset {\cal T}$ is a basis if and only if satisfies conditions (1) and (2). End.

Now take a set $X$, without topology, and consider the power set $\wp(X)$. If you take ${\cal B}\subset \wp(X)$ and ${\cal B}$ verifies conditions (1) and (2), then there exists a unique topology on $X$ which has $\cal B$ as a basis. End.

Ok?

Comment: so, can I think that there always at least one nonempty elements belongs to two basis elements?

Comment: Not necessarily. Condition (2) says that **if** $x \in B_1$ and $x\in B_2$, there must be $B_3 \in {\cal B}$ verifying $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Thing is, if $x$ is contained in only one element of $\cal B$, condition (2) holds always.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal T$  and $\mathcal T'$ are not the topologies generated by base $\mathcal B$.

Comment: what bases generated $\mathcal{T}$ and  $\mathcal{T'}$?